# Shell script grep alternative

Tags: php, regex, shell, grep

How can I replace grep?

```
CONNECTION=$( grep $INST\; $CONNFILE | cut -d\; -f2) || exit 3;
```

I getting below error message under my PHP page:

"Received value grep: session_inactive;: No such file or directory"

Comment: Have you tried `grep "$INST;"` or  `grep "${INST};"`? I'm guessing your INST variable may contain spaces.

Comment: That's rather a big leap, to ask "how can I replace grep?" instead of "how can I fix the way I'm using grep?"

Comment: ...as an aside, all-caps names are used for variables with meaning to the OS or shell; consider making a habit of using lowercase names for your own variables, as these are [reserved by POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap08.html) for application use and guaranteed not to modify behavior of the shell or POSIX-specified OS utilities. And consider making a habit of using http://shellcheck.net/ before asking questions here -- which would have, for instance, pointed out the missing quotes.

Comment: PHP code doesn't accept grep. 

Is it possible replace it by awk or sed?

Comment: @MárcioMoreno, that's simply untrue. It's nothing to do with your code being PHP, and everything to do with the variable containing your search string being improperly quoted. (If your code you're searching for doesn't evaluate to itself as a regex, that might be an additional issue that calls for some non-default arguments, but we'd need to see the actual/exact search string in use to support that conclusion -- and it doesn't mean you *can't use* grep, but means you need to use grep differently).

Comment: Anyhow, if you want to get more useful responses rather than bare assertions that you're Doing It Wrong, [edit] your question to include a [mcve] that anyone else can run to see the same problem, without having an identical `INST` variable already defined or a `CONFFILE` present.

Comment: I'm shell script noob :D 

CONNFILE="$SCRIPTDIR/credentials"
CONNECTION=$( grep "${INST};" | $CONNFILE | cut -d\; -f2) || exit 3;

now I'm having below message

./check_ora.sh: line 169: /etc/zabbix/externalscripts/check_ora/credentials: Permission denied

Comment: `foo | bar` means that you run both `foo` and `bar` as programs, with the output of the first connected to the input of the second. Thus, `grep "${INST};" | $CONNFILE` means you're trying to run `$CONNFILE` as a program -- so it needs executable permissions, which of course it doesn't have.

Comment: `grep "${INST};" "$CONNFILE"` is more likely to be correct.

Comment: That said, are you trying to match on the first semicolon-delimited field, and print the second? If so, I wouldn't grep the entire lines, but would search only for an *exact* match on that field only. Substring searches add extra things to go wrong -- searching for `10;`, for instance, will also match `110;`.

Answer (score 0):

First: *There's no reason you can't successfully use `grep` for this job*.

---

However: Since you're trying to trim out an individual field, you might use `awk` to do the job of both `grep` *and* `cut`, while ensuring that it's performing a literal search rather than a pattern match:

```
connfile="$SCRIPTDIR/credentials"
connection=$(awk -F';' -v inst="${INST};" 'index($0, inst) > 0 { print $2; }' <"$connfile")
```

Even better, if what you actually want to do is match on the first field and print the second, and include **only** the first matching line:

```
connection=$(awk -F';' -v inst="${INST};" '$1 == inst { print $2; exit; }' <"$connfile")
```

Comment: Charles,

Even after changing expression I'm facing same under Zabbix.

Comment: I'd need a [mcve]. As it is, nobody but you can see your problem.

Comment: Charles,

Even after changing expression I'm facing same error under Zabbix page.
        CONNECTION=$(awk -F';' -v inst="${INST};" 'index($0, inst) > 0 { print $2; }' <"$CONNFILE")


PS: Script works fine while running on terminal.

Comment: To repeat myself a third time: You need to provide a reproducer. If nobody else can see your problem, nobody else can solve your problem. It can't be *that* hard to write a little PHP script that embeds this shell command in the same way you're doing so otherwise. **That said**, that should be done in a different/separate question, since you didn't tag this one PHP.